# How do I calculate a rolling standard deviation across both rows and columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe to start with:
[Starting dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLMfa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLMfa.png)

And I need to calculate the rolling 6 month standard deviations for each period (where possible). For example, the standard deviation for April 2023 should be standard deviation of (-1.08,2.6,-0.36,-1.92,-0.84,0.01) = 1.55. In other words, I want the rolling standard deviations to loop back around to December if there is not 6 data points to the left of a given month.

I started by creating a copy and removing the years, and I will merge the proper result (once I have them) back in with a dataframe containing the years. This results in : [image]

Here is my code to calculate the rolling standard deviations.

```
#Input the length of rolling periods in months to use when calculating tracking errors
def get_tracking_errors(months):
    tracking_errors = {}
    for i in range(len(fundslist)):
        temp_df = diffs_to_acwi[fundslist[i]].copy(deep=True)
        #Copy the temporary dataframe while excluding Year to perform the moving standard deviation
        temptemp = temp_df.copy(deep=True)
        cols = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
        temptemp = temptemp[cols]
        temptemp = temptemp.rolling(months,axis=1).std()
```

[image]
The image I have shared above is of a returned "temptemp" dataframe with the standard deviation applied.
Clearly, the calculation does not loop around like it is supposed to . I wondered if anyone knew of a solution to this issue.

Comment: An image of a dataframe doesn't do much for the people who want to help you out. You're example data should be copy-pasteable into a python interpreter/

Comment: Good point, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch the "circular" logic I will treat the values as a flat list in the logical order to calculate the std. As an example I will only use the first three rows of your dataset:

Dummy data:

```
vals_1= [-1.92,0.36,2.6,-1.08,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
vals_2 = [-3.02,-2.11,0.25,0.36,-0.7,1.42,2.14,0.17,2.5,0.01,-0.84]
vals_3 = [-.14,-1.14,0.27,-0.34,-0.62,3.3,3.93,-3.35,2.78,4.67,-0.33]

df = pd.DataFrame({'0':vals_1,
                   '1':vals_2,
                   '2':vals_3}).T
df.columns = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
```

Flattened list of standard deviations (I'm using x[::-1] to inverse the positions of the rows):

```
stds = pd.Series(np.array([x[::-1] for x in df.values]).flatten()).rolling(6).std()
```

Outputs:

```
output = pd.DataFrame([stds.values.tolist()[11*i:11*(i+1)] for i in range(int(np.ceil(len(stds)/11)))],
                      columns = df.columns)
```

Returning:

```
        Jan       Feb       Mar  ...       Oct       Nov       Dec
0       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN  1.569838  1.805972  ...  1.009825  1.511419  1.665193
2  1.358657  2.671217  2.913587  ...  2.699418  2.160898  1.580334
```